# How to restore changed files with repo?

Tags: android, git, version-control, repository

I working with [repo](http://source.android.com/source/using-repo.html) command.

1. I initialize some folder with command `repo init -u URL`
2. I download files with command `repo sync`
3. Then I  have changed something in files (i am applied the patch that changed the files.)

How i can restore original files, before they was changed with patch.

And  can I specify files that do not need to be restored?

Comment: I think there should be a commit created when you apply the patch. Can you check `git log` to see whether one is created?

Comment: It's repo and it doen't have log command.

Comment: `repo` is a script on top of `git`, underneath your files you have a git repository, you do stuff on it with both `git` and `repo`.

Comment: @Pepelac: Underlying is still `git`. `repo` is just a wrapper.

Comment: but if i try `repo log`    
repo: 'log' is not a repo command.  See 'repo help'.     
And if i try `git log`   
fatal: Not a git repository

Comment: If `git log` is returning that message, it means you haven't changed directory into the git repository. Once you're in the proper directory, you can restore any files with `git checkout -- filename`

Comment: It's repo. I can't use `git` command as i see. Only `repo` command works in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to restore files it's two steps command:
`repo diff >> difference.patch` and next
`patch -p0 -R < difference.patch`

Also you can remove files that don't need to be restored from `difference.patch`